# Moving from Vue3 to Nuxt3 trouble importing vue3-plotly

Tags: vuejs3, plotly.js, nuxt3

So I recently started using the vue3-plotly package for creating plotly plots on vue3. I wanted to move my entire project to Nuxt3 and found it quite difficult to manage this.

I am constantly greeted by this error message

```
at Object. (./node_modules/plotly.js-dist/plotly.js:16:4)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object. (./node_modules/vue3-plotly/dist/library.js:6:14)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
```

I have found a solution for it on nextjs but not sure how to implement it for Nuxt.

https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js/issues/272

It appears that lazy loading a component could solve the problem but am not sure how to do that in nuxt3.

Also, I have tried wrapping the component in `<no-ssr>` tag as well as changing the ssr flag to false on nuxt.config file.

What steps should i take to solve the issue?